Code stopped working Compare Cheapest and highest Price
Recently I started with some courses to learn more about Data Analytics and there I came across Kaggle.
I started today with my 1st notebook integrated in Kaggle using panda related codes. for laptops.training.csv
When I added below code it was working fine, Than I made some changes to other kernels and than the above one stopped working.
The error message conclusion looks simple "Price", but this is how the column is named.
I tried to reset the kernels but keep getting the same problem, and I have no idea why. The other kernels are fine. Found out if that kaggle will not save at all if there is a hidden problem.
Can someone help why the code stopped working and how to get it back working?
Input
#Show most expensive and cheapest laptop with specifications
# Find the most expensive laptop
most_expensive_laptop = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmax()]

# Print information about the most expensive laptop
print("Most expensive laptop:")
print(most_expensive_laptop)

# Find the cheapest laptop
cheapest_laptop = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin()]

# Print information about the cheapest laptop
print("\nCheapest laptop:")
print(cheapest_laptop)

Output:
Most expensive laptop:
Manufacturer                                              Razer
Model Name                                            Blade Pro
Category                                                 Gaming
Screen Size                                               17.3"
Screen                      4K Ultra HD / Touchscreen 3840x2160
CPU                                 Intel Core i7 7820HK 2.9GHz
RAM                                                        32GB
 Storage                                                1TB SSD
GPU                                     Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080
Operating System                                        Windows
Operating System Version                                     10
Weight                                                   3.49kg
Price                                                54232308.0
Name: 196, dtype: object

Cheapest laptop:
Manufacturer                                       Asus
Model Name                              Vivobook E200HA
Category                                        Netbook
Screen Size                                       11.6"
Screen                                         1366x768
CPU                         Intel Atom x5-Z8350 1.44GHz
RAM                                                 2GB
 Storage                             32GB Flash Storage
GPU                               Intel HD Graphics 400
Operating System                                Windows
Operating System Version                             10
Weight                                           0.98kg
Price                                         1706374.8
Name: 20, dtype: object

ERROR Message ->
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3805, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3804 try:
-> 3805     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3806 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:196, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7081, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7089, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Price'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[594], line 3
      1 #Show most expensive and cheapest laptop with specifications
      2 # Find the most expensive laptop
----> 3 most_expensive_laptop = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmax()]
      5 # Print information about the most expensive laptop
      6 print("Most expensive laptop:")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:1121, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
   1118     return self._values[key]
   1120 elif key_is_scalar:
-> 1121     return self._get_value(key)
   1123 # Convert generator to list before going through hashable part
   1124 # (We will iterate through the generator there to check for slices)
   1125 if is_iterator(key):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:1237, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1234     return self._values[label]
   1236 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1237 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1239 if is_integer(loc):
   1240     return self._values[loc]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3812, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3807     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3808         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3809         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3810     ):
   3811         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3812     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3813 except TypeError:
   3814     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3815     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3816     #  the TypeError.
   3817     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Price'

I deleted the code, re-entered. tried to change the name
Restarted the Kernel
Restarted all Kernels and clear output.
